# NSJSONSerialization: "No value" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, nsjsonserialization

I used `NSJSONSerialization` for converting `NSdata` in an ios application.

Here is my code:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{ // getting 1 byte data
    if (error)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        NSError *errorData = nil;
        id responseObject1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&errorData];

        // error : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value.) UserInfo=0x78e43130 {NSDebugDescription=No value.}

        if (!errorData)
        {
        } ......
    }
}
```

Here are my json data:

```
{"root":{"status":true,"info":"Inserted"}}
```

And I get 1 byte of data after sending request.

But it's not converting data. It gives a "No value" error at parsing time:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value.) UserInfo=0x78e43130 {NSDebugDescription=No value.}

Please help me: what is the problem?

Comment: Getting one byte data? You mean that [data length] = 1 ? Really? Which one? How is it supposed to be valid JSON after response?

Comment: Try: `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&errorData];`

Comment: If you `NSLog(@"%@", data)`, what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
id responseObject1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&errorData];
```